# How to add Swift Package to DEBUG builds only?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

How to add a dependency that only needs when building with Debug configuration?

Or better yet, how to exclude a Swift Package from Release configuration?

> I tried to use `EXCLUDED_SOURCE_FILE_NAMES` build settings, but package sources are not directly linked.

Comment: Hi mate, any luck with this?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a Framework for debug libraries, and exclude the actual framework file from Release builds. ✨

1. Add the *Swift Package* to the project
2. Create a framework called `DebugPackages`
3. Add the Swift Package to the framework at *General/Frameworks and Libraries*
4. Add `DebugPackages.framework` to the *Build Options/Excluded Source File Names* build setting in Release configuration.